# MySQL Query can't get the result when using left join of multiple table to just one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use LEFT JOIN of multiple table to single one:

```
SELECT unit.unit_id,
       unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_situation_legal_protection_id,
       situation.situation_id,
       situation.situation_type,
       legal.legal_id,
       legal.legal_type,
       protection.protection_id,
       protection.protection_type,
       unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_situation_legal_protection_date_added,
       unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_situation_legal_protection_status
FROM unit
LEFT JOIN unit_situation_legal_protection ON unit.unit_id = unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_id
LEFT JOIN situation ON unit_situation_legal_protection.situation_id= situation.situation_id
LEFT JOIN legal ON unit_situation_legal_protection.legal_id = legal.legal_id
LEFT JOIN protection ON unit_situation_legal_protection.protection_id=protection.protection_id
WHERE unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_id = 146
```

Where I need to get the `legal_type`, `protection_type`, and `situation_type` from their respective tables and add them to the returned rows.

I can get the `legal_id`, `protection_id` and `situation_id` from the result, but `legal_type`, `protection_type`, and `situation_type` are always empty.

**EDIT: Explanation**

There are 5 tables:

The `unit` table which is the main one, and `unit_situation_legal_protection` which is connected to `unit` through `unit_id` as a foreign key.

`unit_situation_legal_protection` have other foreign keys like `legal_id`, `protection_id` and `situation_id`. Each table of them having separate table containing `id` and `type`.

So the situation table contains: `situation_id` and `situation_type`.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and expected output? I know it requires some work, but it just makes it way easier for those trying to help you.

Comment: If you can get the id column but not the type column from some tables then the type column is most certainly empty for those tables. Have you looked at those tables separately?

Comment: Check the edited question guys.

Comment: Yes. I have data inside these tables.

Comment: Simplify your question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @droidnation . . . You are getting empty values because you are using `LEFT JOIN`s and there are no matching values for the joins.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_id = 146` makes a `join` from your `left join`. Remove the `where` clause and add it to the join:

```
SELECT unit.unit_id,
       unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_situation_legal_protection_id,
       situation.situation_id,
       situation.situation_type,
       legal.legal_id,
       legal.legal_type,
       protection.protection_id,
       protection.protection_type,
       unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_situation_legal_protection_date_added,
       unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_situation_legal_protection_status
FROM unit
LEFT JOIN unit_situation_legal_protection ON unit.unit_id = unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_id and unit_situation_legal_protection.unit_id = 146
LEFT JOIN situation ON unit_situation_legal_protection.situation_id= situation.situation_id
LEFT JOIN legal ON unit_situation_legal_protection.legal_id = legal.legal_id
LEFT JOIN protection ON unit_situation_legal_protection.protection_id=protection.protection_id
```

Comment: Nope. It returned all rows even those that aren't related, and no types displayed.

Comment: OK, probably a good suggestion at least, but what about records where the `unit_id` was actually 146?  Wouldn't you expect to see data in that case?  The OP reports seeing no data whatsoever.

Comment: I will make an sql fiddle and gets back to you.